# Feather icons not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like to use feather-icons in Asp.net Core cshtml files. I followed their github steps but it won't show as it is stated in the docs:

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Home">
                    <i data-feather="home"></i>
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

_Layout

```
 <script src="~/lib/feather-icons/dist/feather.js"></script>
```

Comment: we tried to guess the source of your unknown code but could not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this code `feather.replace()` in js first.

And you can use online js reference, you can refer to [this](https://github.com/feathericons/feather).

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
    <script>
        feather.replace()
    </script>
} 

<ul class="nav flex-column">

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Home">
            <i data-feather="home"></i>
            Home
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the result:

[image]